# Confused about Xamarin Forms auth to AAD

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have created a mobile app in Azure to use for my XF application, this has created an app in my AAD, I am now reading the following to try and make my XF app auth to that Azure App I created

[XF and AAD Auth](http://www.appzinside.com/2016/02/22/implement-adal-for-cross-platform-xamarin-applications/)

and this

[Auth Azure API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-an-api-management-oauth-20-authorization-server)

This tells me to create a new app of type native which confuses me a little does this mean I need 2 applications in Azure? one for the backend and one for the Mobile auth? It seems very difficult to find a straight forward document that describes this properly when using the configuration options in the mobile app part of Azure.

Any pointers would be very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You need two applications in Azure AD.

- Native app (Xamarin app)
- Web/API (Your back-end API)

Then, your native app should require the permission to call the API. So add that to its required permissions.

You can also add the native app as a *known client* for the API.
This can be done by finding the API's app in Azure AD, clicking Manifest, and then adding the Application Id/Client Id *of the native app* there so that the `knownClientApplications` property looks like this:

```
"knownClientApplications":[
  "your-native-app-client-id"
]
```

The point of doing that is that now when a user logs in, they can do consent for both apps at the same time.

Your native app should then use ADAL to acquire an access token for your API.
You can of course also call other APIs from your native app too, like MS Graph API.

You can actually find a sample app here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget.

The important line is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget/blob/master/DirectorySearcherLib/DirectorySearcher.cs#L37):

```
authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri, parent);
```

The resource URI is important. It specifies to AAD which API you want to call. In the case of Azure AD Graph API it is `https://graph.windows.net`. In the case of MS Graph API it is `https://graph.microsoft.com`. In the case of your back-end API, you can use either the Application Id/Client Id or the Application ID URI found in the API app's Properties.

Client Id here in the call should of course be your native app's Application Id/Client Id.

You can check the Readme for the sample on how to register the native app.